# Trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in a text field Using Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, uitextfield, capitalization

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of each word I put into a text field. I would like to put this code in here:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
//Here
}
```

My issue is that I have no idea what to put. I've tried creating a string like one post told me to do, and I'm having trouble:

```
nameOfString.replaceRange(nameOfString.startIndex...nameOfString.startIndex, with: String(nameOfString[nameOfString.startIndex]).capitalizedString)
```

I am not sure what to put inside that function to capitalize the first letter of each word.

Comment: Why not set the text field's `autocapitalizationType` property to `Words`? Then as the user types, each word will automatically be capitalized.

Comment: @rmaddy why don't you post your comment as as answer? `textField.autocapitalizationType = .Words`

Comment: @LeoDabus Because my comment doesn't answer the question. It's just a quick comment to offer a possible alternate solution. I don't know if the OP actually has a different need.

Comment: try adding a target to your text field for the control events editing changed which calls a method where you can just do something like  textField.text = textField.text?.capitalizedString

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply set Textfield's Capitalization for words.

[image]

Comment: how to make `UIButton` label as Capitalize.

Comment: Changing Capitalisation option not working for me. :-(

Answer (score 8):

From the code side of this question, assuming it's connected with `IBOutlet`.

- If the need is to change the text field behavior:

  ```
  textField.autocapitalizationType = .Words
  ```
- If the need is to change the input for the text field, i.e. the `String` itself:

  ```
  let newText = textField.text?.capitalizedString
  ```
- *Not* asked in the question but yet: to Capitalize just the first letter:

  ```
  let text = textField.text
  let newText = String(text.characters.first!).capitalizedString + String(text.characters.dropFirst())
  ```

Answer (score 3):

This is forced capitalization of the first letter:

```
firstNameTextField.delegate = self

extension YourViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let empty = textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true
        if(empty) {
            textField.text = string.uppercased()
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

}
```